# How to sort and render table in ReactJs properly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, react-native

Help, people :) I made the same function (sorting function) in pure JS, but after sorting, I rendered the table every time, i.e. created a new one with sorted data, but I don’t understand how to implement it in React.

How exactly do I recreate the body of the table every time I do something with the data?

```
 import tableData from './data';
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 import './App.css';

 function App() {
   let [data, setData] = useState(tableData);
   let clickOnPrice = false;

 const sortByPrice = () => {
   let sorted = data;
   if(!clickOnPrice) {
      sorted.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')));
      clickOnPrice = true;
   }else {
      sorted.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')));
      clickOnPrice = false;
   }
 }



return (
<div className='App'>
 <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>№</th>
    <th>Название</th>
    <th><button className='price_btn' onClick={() => sortByPrice()}>Цена<span className="icons descending_icon">&nbsp;↑</span></button></th>
    <th><button className='price_btn'>Количество</button></th>
    <th>В рассрочку</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{index + 1}</td>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td>{item.price}</td>
      <td>{item.count}</td>
      <td>{(item.instalment) ? '✅' : ''}</td>
    </tr>
   ))}
   </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 );
 }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `data` state variable to store sorted data as:

```js
const sortByPrice = () => {
      setData(data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, ''))));   
 }
```

You do not need even the variable named `clickOnPrice` if you want to sort data only in one way (either desc or asc).

Moreover, replace

```
    <th><button className='price_btn' onClick={() => sortByPrice()}>Цена<span className="icons descending_icon">&nbsp;↑</span></button></th>
```

with

```
    <th><button className='price_btn' onClick={sortByPrice}>Цена<span className="icons descending_icon">&nbsp;↑</span></button></th>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it still doesn't work. It is okay with **setData([...data.sort()])** and not working with **setData(data.sort())**. Now I can sort only in **asc**, thx for that again! And how to do it in **desc** without or with **clickOnPrice** variable?

Comment: I've just noticed that setData(data) and setData([...data}) don't show me my array, I get only "undefined", why?

Comment: Let's create a state variabe
const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('default')

you can use sortType to identify which type of sorting you want to implement. Like default value of sortType is `default` so we can put condtions accordingly. if `default`, then setSortType('desc') or if `desc` then setSortType('asc') or if `asc` then setSortType('default').

Comment: [...data] basically creates a copy of data array.
Check sortType and set data accordingly like:
if `default` then `tableData`
if `desc` then `data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')))`
if `asc` then `data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')))`

Comment: If it won't help, then create a new variable in `sortByPrice` like:
`const sortedArray=[...data]`
and then manipulate it and set into `data` state variable

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works, however, when I have "default" I have to click 2 times, I did such conditions:
const sortByPrice = () => {
    if(sortType === 'default') {
      setSortType('desc');
      setData(data);
    }else if(sortType === 'desc') {
      setSortType('asc');
      setData([...data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')))]);
      
    }else if(sortType === 'asc') {
  setSortType('default');
 setData([...data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.price.replace(/ /g, '')) - parseInt(b.price.replace(/ /g, '')))]);
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243050/discussion-between-the-king-arthur-and-hafiz-muhammad-bilal).